# not directory GPIO in image beaglebone sys/class

Tags: gpio, beagleboneblack, libgpiod, yocto-kirkstone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOKCw.png)

I use Yocto "kirkstone" I can't get the GPIO directory out, I use "core-image-minimal" does anyone know a solution to get the "GPIO" directory out.

I use "core-image-minimal".

Comment: You added tag `libgpiod`. It's a library for the new (okay, 5+ years old) ABI for GPIO. It uses character device and that's exactly what you should use.